# Change icon of google map marker when onmouseover div (Google maps v3 api)

Tags: javascript, google-maps

How do i change the icon of a marker on google maps when I mouseover the text in a div? I managed to change the marker icon onmouseover the marker in the map itself using

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, "mouseover", function(event) {
            this.setIcon("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=1|ffffff|c41200");
}
```

**EDIT:**

Here is what I have now:

```
function initialize(){
....
var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({  

            position: new google.maps.LatLng(1.288693,103.846733),

            map: map,

            icon: "http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=1|c41200|ffffff"

        }); 
....
}


function changeMarker(marker) {

            alert(marker);

    }
```

and

```
<div id="searchresult" onmouseover="changeMarker(marker1)">
```

I'm using Chrome. In the console, onmouseover the div I get the error "Uncaught ReferenceError: marker1 is not defined"

Comment: On a side note, I would remove the php tag, since this question has nothing to do with php. I'd do it myself, but I don't yet have the privileges to retag questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a onmouseover property to the div. Let's say it was called changeMarker.

```
function changeMarker(marker) {
    var icon = new Google.maps.MarkerImage({ url:"http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=1|ffffff|c41200"});
    marker.setIcon(icon);
}
```

Your div could then look like:

```
<div onmouseover="changeMarker(marker1)">
```

I would recommend however caching the MarkerImage (since it seems pretty static) so that Google doesn't need to keep regenerating the graph image.

You can set other properties of the image. See the [documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#MarkerImage)

Comment: Sorry, I messed up the formatting in the post. It thought my div tag was html code.

Comment: well i tried this and the marker didnt work... I used the exact same code u posted.. any ideas?

Comment: I had copied your code for setting the icon without checking that it was valid. I'll go fix it now

Comment: thanks matzahboy! but for some reason, onmouseover the div or h1/h2 with the onmouseover code does not cause the marker to change...

Comment: I would check that the onmouseover is even being called (i.e. change it to an alert or a console.log). If that doesn't work, then I'm not sure what the issue is.

Comment: the onmouseover event gets called when i use <div onmouseover="alert('hi')">


when i change it to <div onmouseover="changeMarker()"> and have function changeMarker() {
    alert('hi');
}
the alerts popup too onmouseover

now when i have something inside the changeMarker() parenthesis, it stops calling the alert box!! ie changeMarker(marker)...

Comment: Have you checked whether you are passing it a valid variable (i.e. that marker is an already defined variable)? Try looking at the Javascript Console to see what the error message is. If you don't know what the Javascript Console is, tell me what browser you are using and I will explain.

Comment: I have edited the original post with the code and the error message from the javascript console, please take a look :)

Comment: Marker1 is not at global scope. It is therefore deleted as soon as the function init() ends. Change it from var marker1=... to marker1=...

Answer (score 0):

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, 'mouseover', function () {
    marker1.setIcon('miniMarker.png');                      
 });
```

first call initialize function, define marker1 and then use this code, You can also call this function from different ways like you want on div mouse over etc.

Comment: How does this change the icon on mouseover?

Answer (score -2):

I'm using Chrome. In the console, `onmouseover` the `<div>` I get the error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: marker1 is not defined

If you set variable like this:

```
function a() {
  var marker1 = "foo";
}

alert(marker1);
```

marker1 is not accessible at "window" level. You have to write it like this:

```
var marker1;

function a() {
  marker1 = "foo";
}

alert(marker1);
```