# Change marker icon on mouseover a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I would like to change the marker icon, when the user hovers his mouse over a div tag. I found a close solution, where the marker icon changes when the user hovers his mouse over the marker itself. But I would like to change it using div tags.

The code:

```
var icon1 = "imageA.png";
var icon2 = "imageB.png";

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map: map,
    id: 1,
    icon: icon1,
    title: "some marker"
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
    marker.setIcon(icon2);
});
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function() {
    marker.setIcon(icon1);
});
```

My set up shall look like this:

```
   <div class="sth" onmouseover="ShowMarker(id)" />
```

And my JS sth like:

```
    var icon1 = "imageA.png";
    var icon2 = "imageB.png";

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        map: map,
        id: 1,
        icon: icon1,
        title: "some marker"
    });

    function ShowMarker(id) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
        marker[id].setIcon(icon2);
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function() {
        marker[id].setIcon(icon1);
    });

}
```

This code should change only the selected marker by id.
 Could anyone change my code to a working one? 
I would really appreciate it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change icon of google map marker when onmouseover div (Google maps v3 api)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6049636/change-icon-of-google-map-marker-when-onmouseover-div-google-maps-v3-api)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to make a listener on the div you want :

`<div class="sth" onmouseover="hover(1)" onmouseout="out(1)">MARKER 1</div>
<div class="sth" onmouseover="hover(2)" onmouseout="out(2)">MARKER 2</div>`

Then push your markers in another variable, and loop on it :

```
var allMarkers = [];
var marker = new ...();
allMarkers.push(marker);

function hover(id) {
    for ( var i = 0; i< allMarkers.length; i++) {
        if (id === allMarkers[i].id) {
           allMarkers[i].setIcon(icon2);
           break;
        }
    }
}

...
```

I've done a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mzhnvcnh/1/), with comments. Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer. I noticed that your code is changing both of the markers unfortunately. I would like to change only one specific marker, this is why I gave the id: property. :)

Comment: Sorry, here the solution I hope [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mzhnvcnh/1/) ^^

(I update the answer above)

Comment: I achieved the same thing using 

    function hover(id) {
       allMarkers[id].setIcon(icon2);
    }

Anyway great answer :D

Comment: Is there any way that I can do that but getting the markers list at runtime? I have the id of the map and the id of the marker but not the array.

So I need to get the array, do the loop and the push